# View model won't update in Knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I'm familiar with React, and not as familiar with Knockout.  I expected that once I assigned a value to an observable it would be reflected immediately... but that is not happening for some reason.

```
<span data-bind="text: myMessage"></span>

 <script>
        var viewModel;

        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/document/",
            dataType: "json",
            method: "GET"
        }).done(function (data) {
            viewModel = {
                myMessage: ko.observable()
            };

            viewModel.myMessage(data[0].Name);
        }).fail(function() {
            alert("something totally awful just happened.");
        });

    </script>
```

this ajax call is returning a text string, I've confirmed it's working just fine.  Is there a reason the span is not showing up on the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the view model once, apply it to the DOM and update it in the AJAX call:

```
<span data-bind="text: myMessage"></span>

 <script>
        var viewModel =  {
            myMessage: ko.observable()
        };
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/document/",
            dataType: "json",
            method: "GET"
        }).done(function (data) {
            viewModel.myMessage(data[0].Name);
        }).fail(function() {
            alert("something totally awful just happened.");
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: thanks, I'll accept in 7 minutes.  I just jumped right in without really reading the documentation I guess, thank you and I do feel lazy :)

Answer (score -1):

You're missing `ko.applyBindings(viewModel);`

```
<span data-bind="text: myMessage"></span>

<script>
    var viewModel;

    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/document/",
        dataType: "json",
        method: "GET"
    }).done(function (data) {
        viewModel = {
            myMessage: ko.observable()
        };

        viewModel.myMessage(data[0].Name);
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    }).fail(function() {
        alert("something totally awful just happened.");
    });

</script>
```

Comment: This is wasteful and won't work in multiple succeeding AJAX calls.